# Facebook timeline icon

Tags: facebook, icons, facebook-timeline

I have this problem with my tab icon. The 'Support' icon that I have on my tab will automatically changed into some other weird image from time to time.

This probably happens like once a day or two.

Can anyone let me know what's the cause for that?

Other than this I love the new Facebook Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem using the Static HTML (iFrame) app for tabs/views - the issue in that case is that there apparently is a limit to the number of custom images that can be used with an app - 0-9999, so new images may displace old images and you can get an undesired result (someone else's image) due to caching and the way FB is assigning a number to your image. I'd say this is a pretty huge bug that needs to be addressed immediately. Maybe this experience will help lead you to a solution. See this link: http://blog.woobox.com/2012/03/facebook-page-tab-images-changing/

DW